# Como se conectar ao MySQL apenas uma vez, sem precisar instanciar sempre?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como faço para efetuar conexão com o MySQL apenas uma vez, sem precisar escrevê-la novamente em toda função?

Atualmente eu faço assim:

```
class Site {
    var $driver;
    var $host;
    var $dbname;
    var $user;
    var $pass;

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;        
    }
    public function jazz() {
        $d = new PDO("$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->user","$this->pass");
        $d->query('SELECT name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC');
    }
    public function buzz() {
        $c = new PDO("$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->user","$this->pass");
        $c->query('SELECT name, age FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: Se o banco é o mesmo para os dois métodos não porque criar duas conexões.

Comment: Utiliza um Design Pattern.

Comment: Na verdade, dois Design Patterns, cada um pra solucionar parte do problema. **Especificamente** no seu caso, dfepois de implementado os Patterns, você teria no seu construtor uma propriedade que receberia o link de conexão armazenado pelo Pattern (Registry) e, então, passaria a usar essa propriedade como objetos de conexão. Ou você resgataria o link de dentro da caixa em cada método, tanto faz.

Comment: Ou então salvar o objeto como propriedade da classe. Nessa situação Registry com Singleton é matar formiga com bazooca.

Comment: Concordo discordando, pois tudo depende da complexidade da Aplicação. Claro que a aplicabilidade do Registry num projeto quase sempre se restringe à apenas perpetuar um ou mais link(s) de conexão do Application Controller até a Model, mas como não se sabe o quê mais a Aplicação faz, pode ser que exista algum outro recurso que precise de uma instância única. Eu mesmo duvido das minhas próprias palavras, mas também, acho que não tinha nenhuma resposta quanto à esse problema no site ainda. Não que eu sequer tenha pesquisado também... :P

Answer (score 6):

O ideal seria quebrar esse código em duas classes uma só para a conexão do banco(caso ele mude a alteração ficaria apenas em um lugar) e outra para o site, nessa última o construtor receberia a conexão no lugar de usuario, senha, banco etc.

A palavra chave `var` era usada no php4 para definir váriaveis membros de classe no php5 utlize-se os modificadores de acesso:

- `private` Esses membros só podem ser acessados pela classe.
- `protected` Esses membros são visiveis nos objetos e nos decentedes(herança).
- `Public` Qualquer um pode esses atributos.

---

```
class Site {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function jazz() {
        return $this->db->query('SELECT name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC');
    }

    public function buzz() {
        return $this->db->query('SELECT name, age FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Existem duas possibilidades para se solucionar esse problema, sendo uma delas menos apropriada do ponto de vista da Orientação a Objetos mas, talvez, mais aproveitável para o seu caso em particular.

As propriedades de uma classe servem para armazenar tudo aquilo de que a classe, aravés de seu objeto, possa precisar durante a Requisição na qual foi instanciado.

Se você tem vários métodos que agem como *wrappers* para a parte repetitiva da PDO e todos eles usam o mesmo objeto, ao invés de abrir uma conexão para cada método, você armazena a instância da PDO numa classe, assim:

```
class Site {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
        $this -> conn = new PDO( /** ... */ );
    }

    public function jazz() {
        return $this -> conn -> query( /** ... */ );
    }
}
```

A segunda alternativa é um pouquinho mais complexa, mas muito mais oportuna do ponto de vista da Orientação a Objetos pois, no cenário ideal, você não deve restringir o acesso aos seus dados à apenas um banco de dados e muito menos forçar o uso da PDO.

Nesses casos, utilizando um Design Pattern chamado [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) você tem uma implementação Orientada a Objetos de, basicamente, uma grande caixa, onde você pode guardar o que quiser pra usar depois:

```
class Registry {

    private $registry = array();

    /**
     * Add/Set a Registry Entry value
     *
     * @param string $key
     *  Registry Key
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     *  Value to be stored
     *
     * @return Registry
     *  Registry Object (Fluent Interface)
     */
    public function set( $key, $value ) {

        $key = trim( $key );

        if( ! empty( $key ) ) {

            $this -> registry[ $key ] = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get a Registry Entry value
     *
     * @param string $key
     *  Registry Key
     *
     * @return mixed
     *  Registry Entry
     */
    public function get( $key ) {

        $key   = trim( $key );

        return ( array_key_exists( $key, $this -> registry ) ? $this -> registry[ $key ] : FALSE );
    }
}
```

Porém, sozinho, o Registry não soluciona o problema do estado do objeto, que é justamente o que tange o seu problema.

Sem solucionar esse problema, você se veria:

- Duplicando código, como atualmente deve estar fazendo
- Criar uma variável global e acessá-la no escopo local dos métodos utilizado a palavra-chave **global** ou o array superglobal **$GLOBALS**, o que é extremamente errado

Para solucionar esse "problema" do Registry, já que não é exatamente um problema ele não resolver que não foi desenhado para resolver, basta integrá-lo à outro Design Pattern, o [Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton).

O Singleton é um padrão que visa tornar a instância de um objeto única. Não importa onde no código você invoque o objeto, ele vai sempre ser o mesmo, inclusive com as mesmas propriedades preenchidas nos "níveis" anteriores.

> Com **níveis** me refiro ao fluxo verical e crescente da Aplicação. Os níveis mais baixos seriam arquivos de primeira instância, como **index.php** ou em sistemas mais elaborados um [FronController](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html) e com níveis mais altos, os [Action/Page Controllers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html) ou as Models.

Singleton um padrão bastante útil, se usado do jeito correto.

O uso irrefreado desse padrão no passado deu à ele uma péssima reputação entre os programadores experientes pois quando você abusa do Singleton, você simplesmente deixando variáveis globais "bonitinhas".

Mas aliado ao Registry, criando o que chamamos de Singleton Registry, você tem uma grande caixa acessível em qualquer escopo para guardar tudo aquilo que precisa ser usado em qualquer parte do código.

Vejamos como fica:

```
/**
 * Registry Class
 *
 * @author        Bruno Augusto
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) 2010 Next Studios
 * @license       http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/   Attribution 3.0 Unported
 */
class Registry {

    /**
     * Registry Instance
     *
     * @staticvar Registry $_instance
     */
    private static $_instance;

    /**
     * Registry Storage
     *
     * @var array $registry
     */
    private $registry = array();

    /**
     * Enforcing Singleton. Disallow Cloning
     */
    private function __clone() {}

    /**
     * Enforcing Singleton. Disallow Direct Constructor
     */
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Get Registry Instance
     *
     * @return Registry
     *  Registry Instance
     */
    public static function getInstance() {

        if( NULL === self::$_instance ) {

            self::$_instance = new Registry;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Add/Set a Registry Entry value
     *
     * @param string $key
     *  Registry Key
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     *  Value to be stored
     *
     * @return Next\Components\Registry
     *  Registry Object (Fluent Interface)
     */
    public function set( $key, $value ) {

        $key = trim( $key );

        if( ! empty( $key ) ) {

            $this -> registry[ $key ] = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get a Registry Entry value
     *
     * @param string $key
     *  Registry Key
     *
     * @return mixed
     *  Registry Entry
     */
    public function get( $key ) {

        $key   = trim( $key );

        return ( array_key_exists( $key, $this -> registry ) ? $this -> registry[ $key ] : FALSE );
    }
}
```

Percebeu a diferença?

Nós bloqueamos acesso ao construtor do objeto, assim ele não pode ser instanciado com o operador **new**, que é o que faz a instância do objeto mudar.

> Crédito Extra: Para ver uma representação da variação da instância de um objeto, passe a instância como argumento para [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/spl_object_hash)

Mas para trabalhar com objetos é preciso instânciá-lo e você vai sim instanciar a classe Registry, mas indiretamente através do método estático *Registry::getInstance()*.

Esse método consulta uma propridade estática e verifica se existe uma instância do objeto guardada nela. Se não existir, significa que o Registry está sendo usado pela primeira vez, então ela é criada.

Nas outras vezes, nos níveis mais altos, essa instância já existe e ao invés de ser criada novamente, ela é retornada do jeito que estiver.

E com "do jeito que estiver" quero dizer com tudo que estiver dentro dessa grande caixa, no seu caso, seu objeto de conexão, o qual você seta através de *Registry::set()* e resgata através de *Registry::get()*. Vamos ver?

```
$link = new Site( /** ... */ );
Registry::getInstance() -> set( 'link', $link );

// Em alguma outra parte do código DEPOIS de adicionar o objeto à caixa

$link = Registry::get( 'link' );

$link -> prepare( '/** ... */' );

// ...
```

:D

Comment: Resposta boa, mas acho que irá somente confundir ainda mais o OP. Entendi que o que ele deseja é exatamente o que o perdeu respondeu: instanciar o objeto de conexão em uma propriedade da classe.

Comment: Melhor complementar então

Comment: Ou simplificar :P

Answer (score 4):

Para isso acontecer você iria precisar retornar o objeto PDO criado diretamente pela classe, tente algo como:

```
class DB{
    private static $conn = null;
    private static $tns = "Connection String";
    private static $db_username = '<USERNAME>';
    private static $db_password = '<SENHA>';

    private function __construct(){

    }

    public static function conn(){
        if(is_null(self::$conn)){
            try{
                self::$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".self::$tns,self::$db_username,self::$db_password);
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                self::$conn = die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return self::$conn;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        self::$conn = null;
    }
}
```

Note que no método conn(), ele faz uma verificação para saber se o objeto é nulo ou não, caso ele não seja nulo, significa que já há uma conexão instanciada pela classe estática, então ele retorna o próprio objeto, sem instanciar uma nova classe.