# O correto não é conectar o banco somente uma vez e depois percorrer os registros?

Tags: php, construtor

```
<?php
class Usuario {

    private $login;
    private $senha;
    private $admin;

    //variaveis internas
    private $bd; //conexão com o banco
    private $tabela; //nome da tabela

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bd = new BD();
        $this->tabela = "usuario";
    }


    public function listar($complemento = "") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabela ".
                $complemento;

        $resultado = pg_query($sql);
        $retorno = NULL;
        //percorre os registros
        while ($reg = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            //transforma em objetos categoria
            $obj = new Usuario();                  // mudar
            $obj->login = $reg["login"];
            $obj->senha = $reg["senha"];
            $obj->admin = $reg["admin"];
            //adiciona a variavel de retorno
            $retorno[] = $obj;
        }
        return $retorno;
    }
}
?>
```

Nessa parte:

```
while ($reg = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    //transforma em objetos categoria
    $obj = new Usuario();                  // mudar
    $obj->login = $reg["login"];
    $obj->senha = $reg["senha"];
    $obj->admin = $reg["admin"];
    //adiciona a variavel de retorno
    $retorno[] = $obj;
}
```

Ao criar um objeto do tipo `Usuario` dentro do `while`, ele não vai ficar conectando toda hora no banco? no `construct` ele está fazendo iniciando a conexão com o banco, não é? isso funciona, mas o correto não é  conectar o banco somente uma vez e depois percorrer os registros?

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->bd = new BD();
    $this->tabela = "usuario";
}
```

Classe BD:

```
class BD {
    public function __construct() {
        pg_connect("host=localhost user=postgres 
            password=123 dbname=ss port=5432")
                or die("Erro ao conectar ao servidor");
    }
}
```

Comment: editei e atualizei...

Comment: Tem 2 questões interessantes que podem ser uteis pro seu caso: [**questão 1**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/13412), [**questão 2**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43242/13412)

Answer (score 2):

Sim, o correto seria estabelecer a conexão uma única vez. Para isso basta não colocares a conexão no construtor e fazê-la a parte.
Ou então como disse o @chambelix, usar a variável bd como *static*. E nesse caso não seria necessário instanciar a classe para utilizar a bd.

Já agora isso está a funcionar? Não deveria. A não ser que já tenha aberto a conexão alguma vez antes de usar essa classe.

Fica o código:

```
<?php
class Usuario {

    private $login;
    private $senha;
    private $admin;

    //variáveis internas  
    //private $bd;           // sem static

    private static $bd;                          
    private $tabela; //nome da tabela

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tabela = "usuario";
        if(!isset(self::$db)) {       //sem static retirar
            self::$db = new DB();     //estas linhas
        }
    }

    //sem static
    //private function connect() {
    //    
    //    $this->bd = new BD();
    //    return $this->bd;
    //}

    public function listar($complemento = "") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabela ".
                $complemento;   

        //sem static
        //$connection = $this->connect();                       
        //$resultado  = pg_query($connection, $sql);

        $resultado  = pg_query(self::$db, $sql);
        $retorno    = NULL;
        //percorre os registros
        while ($reg = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            //transforma em objetos categoria
            $obj = new Usuario();                 
            $obj->login = $reg["login"];
            $obj->senha = $reg["senha"];
            $obj->admin = $reg["admin"];
            //adiciona a variavel de retorno
            $retorno[] = $obj;
        }
        return $retorno;
    }
}
?>
```

Repara que utilizei a conexão a BD para fazer a *query* como é recomendado na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-query.php):

> Nota: connection é um parâmetro opcional para pg_query(). Se
>   connection não for definido, a conexão padrão será usada. A conexão
>   padrão é a última conexão feita por pg_connect() ou pg_pconnect().
>   Apesar de connection poder ser omitido, isso não é recomendado já que
>   pode ser uma causa de erros difíceis de encontrar no seu script.

Comment: Mas se no caso ele tiver que implementar *Usuarios* e *Administradores* ainda assim `new BD()` será instanciado 2 vezes criando 2 conexões.

Comment: @PapaCharlie a que situação se refere?

Comment: @chambelix feito, era esta a tua ideia?

Comment: @JorgeB. olha vê a minha edição. passa os comentários a um código definitivo.

Comment: @JorgeB. e definitivamente passa de public static para private static claramente.

Comment: @chambelix está bom assim para você? :P

Comment: @JorgeB. sim...feito. =)

Comment: @chambelix, @JorgeB., você aplicou um `Singleton` no que seria um modelo. Quer dizer que pode invocar `$usuarios-> listar(...)` ou qualquer outro método da classe *Usuarios* que será garantido apenas **1** instância do `DB`. Mas se por algum motivo o controller requisitar outro model - `$blogs-> ultimos(...)` - esse ainda não possui `self::$db` e vai fazer uma **NOVA** conexão com o DB independentemente da anterior...

Comment: Se o `Singleton` fosse aplicado no `DB`, funcionaria corretamente, mesmo ignorando as discussões das questões que trouxe como auxilio. A classe `DB` deve garantir que ela fará uma unica conexão com do DB-X ou o DB-Y.

Comment: Tens razão @PapaCharlie.

Comment: @JorgeB. esse é um assunto antigo, por isso recomendei as 2 questões como referência. Se você jogar esse `Singleton` na `DB`, pode fazer um `connector` até bem simples e eficiente.

Comment: @PapaCharlie no contexto da pergunta/resposta self::$db terá sempre a instancia de DB pois é STATIC, pelo que não estou a entender o seu ponto. Ao indicar que pode existir uma chamada $blogs->ultimos(...) não terá na mesma acesso ao self::$db, ao que eu analiso não posso concordar. Desculpe mas talvez eu tenha entendido mal o seu ponto de vista.

Comment: @chambelix o que o PapaCharlie quer dizer é que essa instanciação da BD deveria estar fora da classe.

Comment: @JorgeB. se for esse o caso e num contexto de várias classes concordo... mas no contexto da pergunta um instância para a classe penso que está bem.